# SSMS19 Edit 200 rows shows 'Unknown' in the table (Show Criteria Pane)

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

1. I've created a serverless database in Azure from the Azure portal
2. Connected to the database with SSMS19
3. Created a table with:
   [New Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4fGx.png)
4. Edit 200 Top rows to see the table content: [Edit 200 Top Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85wvQ.png)
5. Selected Show Criteria Pane and saw the problem: [Show Criteria Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQb1z.png)

Instead of the Table being "Table_1" it shows "<Unknown>". I've tried in other databases and the same problem appears in the Views: [View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrdDb.png), although when I execute the SQL it works.

I've tried with SSMS18 and the result is the same. I've tried to convert a database from my local SQL to Azure and is the same. I've tried to create the table with SQL command and is the same...

Comment: Just chalk this up to another reason to *not* use the designer in my opinion. They are well known to be buggy, quirky, and lack functionality. They are as good as deprecated. Avoid them. The "Edit top 200 rows" is probably one of the worst of them. Use an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the comments provided by Erin Stellato (Microsoft) on [this forum thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187830/ssms-table-in-azure-design-shows-(unknown)) on Microsoft QA, it seems this is a SSMS bug. Please follow the instructions I provided on the comments of this thread to get a free support ticket and get help from Azure Support.

This is how to reproduce the issue with SSMS 19.0.2:

1. Create an Azure SQL database that has a period in the name (for
   example, Customer.Issue)
2. Create a table in the database (create table    test1 (col1 int, col2 varchar(10)))
3. Right-click on the new table, select Edit Top 200 Rows.
4. With the edit table window open, select the Show Criteria button.
5. When the criteria window opens, the table name will show as

Comment: Hi Alberto, she could not reproduce it, then she connected to my machine and she saw the behaviour. Her suggestion was then to open a Azure support ticket, but for that I need to sign at least a 29$/month assistant plan. That is why I'm trying with the community.

Comment: could you make the support ticket?

Comment: Done, thanks a lot for the help Alberto. I'll keep you posted about it.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know you read the comment with the instructions. I will now proceed to delete the comment.

Comment: Alberto, just got contacted by Geetha and I could make the ticket. THANKS!!!

Comment: I am glad for you. Thank you for the feedback. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like naming the database with "." makes trouble...
[TestResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw6Y9.png)

Comment: It'd be helpful to have a text description of what you did and the results.  Sometimes images don't work or can't be accessed for various reasons.